# Message received from background. Values reset

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I'm sending post request from "angular->port 4200" to "expressjs server->port 8000".

As an example i'm folowing this example: https://github.com/kuncevic/angular-httpclient-examples/blob/master/client/src/app/app.component.ts

I'm getting two error :

1)undefined from Nodejs(data and req.body.text)

2)Message received from background. Values reset

Angular side:

```
  callServer() {
            const culture = this.getLangCookie().split("-")[0];
            const headers = new HttpHeaders()
            headers.set('Authorization', 'my-auth-token')
            headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            
            this.http.post<string>(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/appculture`, culture, {
              headers: headers
            })
            .subscribe(data => {
            });
        }
```

expressjs side:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path = require('path');

app.all("/*", function(req, res, next){
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With');
    next();
});

app.use( bodyParser.json() );       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     // to support URL-encoded bodies
  extended: true
}));

app.post('/appculture', function (req, res) {
  var currentCulture = `${req.body.text} from Nodejs`;
  req.body.text = `${req.body.text} from Nodejs`;
  res.send(req.body)
})


app.listen(8000, () => {
    console.log('server started');
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular side:

```
 callServer() {
            const culture = this.getLangCookie().split("-")[0];
            const headers = new HttpHeaders()
            headers.set('Authorization', 'my-auth-token')
            headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            
            this.http.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/appculture?c=` + culture, {
              headers: headers
            })
            .subscribe(data => {
            });
        }
```

Nodejs side:

```
app.get('/appculture', function (req, res) {
  currentCulture = req.query.c;
  res.send(req.body)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you are not sending anything of there is no value in `body.text`

Try to `console.log(req.body)` instead of `req.body.text`.

Try to `console.log(culture)` and `this.getLangCookie()` on the client side to see if you are actually sending something.
You can also make use of the network tab in the browser to inspect the request that you are sending.